# Excel.QAT file from Excel2007 to Office365. .QAT replaced by OfficeUI?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to migrate a QuickAccessToolbar in Excel 2007 to a new machine running Office365.  It seems (web searches haven't been any help) that Microsoft has changed the parameter files from xx.QAT to OfficeUI and the location is different.

There is no "IMPORT/EXPORT" function in Excel 2007 in the QAT which is the standard method of migrating the settings.

Any help is appreciated.  Happy New Year.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found on social.technet.microsoft.com

> I just upgraded from 2007 to 2010.  Thanks for the help, I spent
>   months building my QAT, glad to have it back.  My method was very
>   similar:
>
> In Computer A only, navigate to:
>
> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\ Create a copy of
>   Excel.qat;
>
> Rename copy to: Excel.officeUI;
>
> Restart Excel 2010, done.
>
> I also did the same thing to Word and PowerPoint while there.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5064ddb6-b6b3-462a-ace9-7dd937a278ae/migrating-excelqat-2007-file-to-office-2010?forum=officesetupdeployprevious